# Quais tags precisam de vinculação com syntax highlighter?

Tags: debate, tags

Já temos a dica para o *syntax highlighter* do site de qual linguagem provavelmente ele deve escolher o parser em várias *tags*. Algumas ainda não possuem a dica e dificulta a utilização do site. No caso da *tag* ser a própria linguagem, fica fácil. Mas nem todas as outras *tags* são absolutamente claras se deve ou não ter um vínculo.

Quais *tags* devem ter quais linguagens vinculadas para efeito de colorização de sintaxe?

Existe a possibilidade de dicas secundárias?

Answer (score 4):

[android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) -> Java (Me parece que quase todas as perguntas de Android possuem código em Java. Isto não é uma verdade absoluta mas acho que a vinculação seria mais benéfica que maléfica (lembrando que é possível usar uma dica específica quando necessário para as **exceções**). Se isto não for desejável, toda vez que incluir código Java nesta *tag*, ou vai ter que colocar a *tag* [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) ou vai ter que usar o marcador específico no texto.

[ruby-on-rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) -> Ruby.

[python-2.7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) [django](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) -> Python (não tenho certeza se já tem dica desta e de algumas outras).

[.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)[asp.net-mvc-5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5) [webforms](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webforms) [winforms](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) [entity-framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) [linq](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) [nhibernate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate) -> C#. A imensa maioria dos códigos nestas tecnologias usam C#.

[hibernate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate) [jpa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) -> Java

[delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) [pascal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal) -> Pascal.

[ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) [nodejs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) -> JavaScript.

[wordpress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) [laravel-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4) [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) [codeigniter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter) -> PHP.

[css3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) -> CSS.

[r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) -> R.

[xml](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) -> XML.

[twitter-bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) -> CSS/HTML?

[ios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) -> Objective-C.

[qt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) -> C++.

[vb](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb) [vb.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) [vba](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) -> VB.

[oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) [postgresql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) [sql-server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) [sqlite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite)  -> SQL, todos, outros?

Comente se você é contra alguma. Ainda vou pesquisar mais. Coloque sua resposta também.

Comment: eu não sei se é possível associar mais de uma linguagem no syntax highlighter, mas, caso seja, no caso do android também seria interessante associar o `xml`, já que você encontrará bastante material com `xml`.

Comment: Criei associações para quase todas essas tags, exceto as que não existem na interface a que tenho acesso: ios (obj-c), r, delphi, pascal.

Comment: Criei um feature-request no MSE pedindo a inclusão de mais opções para os moderadores: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234056/can-we-have-more-tag-based-syntax-highlighting-options

Answer (score 4):

Várias tags podem ser associadas com Javascript. Pesquise por "jquery" na página de tags e veja derivadas quantas têm:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisando por "angular":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Aparentemente muitas destas tags não tem nenhuma pergunta)

Além destas há [requirejs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requirejs), [ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax), [dom](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom) e possivelmente ainda outras.

Quanto ao [twitter-bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) acho que HTML é mais apropriado que CSS.

Comment: Boa observação apesar de que eu **acho** que dificilmente elas serão usadas isoladamente. Se você usa [tag:jquery-ui], provavelmente vai usar [tag:jquery] também. Ou estou errado? Posso estar, só quem está lidando com as *tags* bem de perto sabe bem.

Comment: @bigown Se você for na wiki de tag do Ruby on Rails, lá diz que essa tag não deve ser usada em conjunto com a tag Ruby. Quando li aquilo, achei que era uma espécie de regra/convenção do StackOverflow para uso de tags. Seguindo essa premissa, teoricamente a tag jQuery não deveria ser usado com Javascript. E jquery-datatables não deveria ser usada com jQuery ou Javascript. Porém posso estar enganado, só digo isso porque li naquela wiki de tag. =P

Comment: Não é algo rígido, é algo definido pela comunidade específica e não para todo o site. E tem muita pergunta com as duas *tags* ([tag:ruby] e [tag:ruby-on-rails] juntas justamente porque falta a dica do *Hilite*.