# Bug na colorização do código da linguaguem delphi/pascal?

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Nessa questão: [Grava mais registros que o Necessario no meu DB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21390/grava-mais-registros-que-o-necessario-no-meu-db), o código pascal não pega a colorização, igual de C#. Utilize geralmente para C# `<!-- language-all: c# -->` e tentei fazer nesse código `<!-- language-all: pascal -->`, `<!-- language-all: delphi -->` mas, mesmo assim ele ficou com o código com apenas uma cor. Tem algum problema ?

Estava também olhando esse link: [Quais tags precisam de vinculação com syntax highlighter?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1438/6026), tem relação ao que eu perguntei ou são coisa distintas ?

Existe algum lugar com todas essas configurações *language/language-all* ?

Comment: eu não sei exatamente como funciona isso, mas eu copiei de uma outra pergunta de delphi e funcionou, olha la

Comment: acabei vendo é lang-delphi, boa @Math, é que fica estranho sem cor na minha opinião!

Comment: Aonde será que tem todas essas configurações @Math ?

Comment: Oonde tem eu não sei, mas onde deveria ter é na pergunta que vc linkou! rs.. Outra coisa, na revisão 4 você colocou `language` sem o `all`, nesse caso ele deveria ir logo antes do código e não tava assim. Caso é claro Pascal fosse o correto pra por na tag

Comment: Apesar que @Math se colocar `<!-- language-all: c# -->` fica igual `<!-- language-all: lang-delphi -->`! a mesma cor!

Comment: Sim, eu fui testando e acabei testando para ver se achava qual era e acabei esquecendo desse detalhe! rs

Comment: poisé, o c# ficou identico, hehehe.. eu nem costumo por esse language aí, só dou 4 espaços e já era, ele sempre reconheceu java automaticamente, que é o código que eu mais costumo usar

Comment: @Math fiz uma edição, e realmente c# nem precisa também colocar mais, estranho esse comportamento de cor.

Comment: [**aqui**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33/3117) tem um monte, só não tem lang-delphi

Comment: A detecção automática é feita através das tags, quem relaciona as linguagens com as tags são os moderadores, veja [**aqui**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66/3117). Talvez a tag Delphi não está mapeada.

Comment: Então, pelo que eu percebi já foram criadas por exemplo C#, a de delphi acho eu que pode ser usada essa (Turbo) Pascal    │  `<!-- language: lang-pascal -->`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A detecção automática é feita através das tags marcadas na pergunta, para isso ocorrer normalmente as tags devem ser relacionadas com as linguagens, quem faz esse mapeamento são os moderadores, de acordo com esse tópico: [**O Syntax Highlight ainda não funciona para várias linguagens**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66/3117).

Provavelmente a tag Delphi não está mapeada, enquanto isso não ocorre use:

```
<!-- language: lang-delphi -->
```

ou

```
<!-- language: lang-pascal -->
```

Perceba que as duas são ligeiramente diferentes.

Nessa publicação existe uma lista de várias linguagens: [**Podemos ter Syntax Highlight nos códigos como no SO?**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/150/3117)

Comment: Só o Gabe pode associar tags a linguagens, se eu pudesse eu faria :(

Comment: @bfavaretto droga, o texto do m0sa tá errado então. Não é moderador que pode alterar, é CM.

Comment: Achei essa opção, oba! Mas na lista que tenho para atribuir à tag, não tem delphi nem pascal :(

Comment: Tentei enganar o sistema forçando o valor `lang-pascal`, mas não rolou.

Comment: @bfavaretto `lang-delphi` não funciona? Será que não tem que esperar um tempo até algum script rodar ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Não, o campo é um `<select>`, e mesmo tentando injetar as opções lang-delphi e lang-pascal, quando submeto o servidor retorna lang-none.

Comment: Criei um feature-request no MSE pedindo a inclusão de mais opções: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234056/can-we-have-more-tag-based-syntax-highlighting-options

Answer (score 1):

Delphi e Pascal não têm predefinições *específicas* de highlighting que podem ser associadas à tag então estão associadas com `lang-default`, que colore *quase* qualquer linguagem *quase* bem.

O resultado não é de todo ruim, como pode ser [visto aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23633/12). Ainda assim, como o @Math disse, o melhor (mais bonito) é usar `<!-- language: lang-delphi -->` ou `<!-- language: lang-pascal -->`.

Mas saiba que estamos melhor que o SOen, onde [delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) e [pascal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal) estão associadas à `none` como highlight padrão.

Comment: Tem como fazer um lobby pro meu [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234056/can-we-have-more-tag-based-syntax-highlighting-options)? :)

Comment: Não mais. Agora temos opções predefinidas para Pascal/Delphi, R e mais algumas linguagens que não tínhamos antes.